# list-ref error with getting 2nd element

Tags: scheme, racket

Why `list-ref` can get the first element, but not the second?

```
> (list-ref (cons 1 2) 0)
1
> (list-ref (cons 1 2) 1)
list-ref: index reaches a non-pair
  index: 1
  in: '(1 . 2)
  context...:
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\private\misc.rkt:87:7
>
```

I'm using DrRacket.

Comment: A `cons` normally holds the first element, and the rest of the list. This means that the second argument should be a list. `2` is not a list. You probably meant `(cons 1 (cons 2 empty))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the list was not correctly built. Try this:

```
(list-ref (list 1 2 3) 1)
```

Remember that a list is built using a `cons` cell which has an element in the `car` part and another `cons` cell in the `cdr` part, or the empty list:

```
(list-ref (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 empty))) 1)
```

Comment: can you elaborate? `'(1 2 3)` is a constant, what about dynamically built list?

Comment: It's not a constant, it's a shortcut equivalent to building the list using cons operations, see my update

Comment: Ok, good to learn that, I'm new to racket and just starting learning the lang. Thanks.

Comment: If you're just learning, it might be easier to start with the teaching languages. If you were in BSL (the first of those) for example, `(cons 1 2)` would be a type error, and it would tell you `cons: second argument must be a list, but received 1 and 2`.

Comment: You wrote `car` twice in your second paragraph. I can't edit a single character.